# Can PHP superglobals be changed or appended with another variable?

Tags: php, session, superglobals

I'm wondering if I do something like `$_SERVER['myVar'] = "myValue"`, does it change in other sessions? Could I access that custom variable from other sessions?

Comment: Of course not. Those variables describe the HTTP connection that triggered the current script, why would you expect them to be shared between different invocations?

Comment: `$_SERVER` isn't even preserved with other invocations in the same session. The only variables preserved in a session are `$_SESSION`.

Comment: My bad, I wanted to mention ```$GLOBALS``` too. Does that work?

Comment: No variables other than `$_SESSION` are shared between processes in a session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm wondering if I do something like $_SERVER['myVar'] = "myValue", does it change in other sessions? Could I access that custom variable from other sessions?

No.

PHP doesn't provide a location to store information that should be shared between multiple visitors to a website. (It has `$_SESSION` for data that should be shared between multiple requests from the *same* visitor).

The usual way to share data between users is to use a database. A file on the filesystem is another option, but databases solve a lot of problems (race conditions, locking, etc) for you.